# How to netinstall to a specific minor release? i.e. 16.04.2

Tags: apt, downgrade

I have a client who wants 16.04.2.  We've always netinstalled 16.04.whatever the lastest in canonical's mirrors is.

We keep a local mirror of Ubuntu, and normally netboot the kernel and initrd:
http://mybox/Ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
http://mybox/Ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz

I use preseed files for my debian/ubuntu installs,  But I don't see a d-i that can specify a minor version.  I'm guessing I need to find a 'repo' that's stuck in 16.04.2  But I can't seem to find one.

So how do I 'make' one?

I don't suppose there's a kernel arg I can send to the installer environment to pin the install to 16.04.2 is there?

Comment: Can I use this .list file perhaps? to override the .list included with the actual live mirror?
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.list

Comment: A 16.04.2 install will be using the 16.10 (HWE) kernel stack, which is now EOL & years past it's supported life. With normal installs it'll end up being 16.04.6 post-install (.2 releases use HWE kernel) so to me the *need* is unsafe (*online anyway*)

Comment: @guiverc  Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Step 1) Download old release from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso
There are a plethora of other obsolete versions at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ as well if you have other idiot clients.

Step 2) mount or extract the iso on your local image server.  Make the mountpoint of the ISO accessible at
mybox.corp.company.com/Distros/Ubuntu-Idiots/16.04.2-server-amd64_mount

Step 3) In your preseed, comment out:

```
#d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
```

Replace with:

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string mybox.corp.company.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /Distros/Ubuntu-Idiots/16.04.2-server-amd64_mount
```

Step 4) Netboot to the new preseed file, and with the mirror hostname and dir being updated to read from the 16.04.2 iso, it will install 16.04.02

Step 5) Profit

OF COURSE:
Old versions are stupid, use the new version. blah blah.